# How do I determine what the correct require statement is for a cocoapod using hyperloop?

Tags: ios, titanium, cocoapods, hyperloop

Question on how to `require` cocoapods in JavaScript using Hyperloop: what is the most reliable way to know the string that is supposed to be passed to the `require` statement for a cocoapod? For example the [Ti docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide-section-46253491_iOSHyperloopProgrammingGuide-CocoaPods) use `pod 'JBChartView'` in their Podfile and subsequently call `require('JBChartView/JBBarChartView')`. How is it determined that `'JBChartView/JBBarChartView'` was the correct string to use in the `require` statement?

The cocoapod I'm trying to do this with is https://github.com/janrain/jump.ios.

I've tried the following require statement path combinations to no avail:

- Janrain
- Janrain/JRConnectionManager
- Janrain/JRConnectionManager/JRConnectionManager
- Janrain/JREngage
- Janrain/JREngage/JRInfoBar
- Janrain/JREngage/JRNativeAuth
- Janrain/JREngage/Classes/JRInfoBar
- Janrain/JREngage/Classes/JRNativeAuth
- Janrain/Janrain/JRConnectionManager
- Janrain/Janrain/JRConnectionManager/JRConnectionManager
- Janrain/Janrain/JREngage
- Janrain/Janrain/JREngage/JRInfoBar
- Janrain/Janrain/JREngage/JRNativeAuth
- Janrain/Janrain/JREngage/Classes/JRInfoBar
- Janrain/Janrain/JREngage/Classes/JRNativeAuth

This is the error I get when attempting require any of those paths:
[image: Hyperloop require statement error]

Answer (score 1):

You structure your require-statement with the framework + class name. So if your framework is called `Janrain` and your class is called `JRConnectionManager`, you require it with `require("Janrain/JRConnectionManager")`. And if you need to require constants/property, you do that by `require`-ing the framework and select the constant/property like this: `require("UIKit").UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`.

However, your error looks like it cannot find the class itself, so you may have problems in your Podfile. Take a look at the [hyperloop-examples](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples) application regarding that. Good luck!